# website wont redirect to https under certain condition for wordpress running on iis

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, iis

For some reason I can't redirect http to https.
Now the catch is it will redirect 
domain.com.au > https://www.domain.com.au
but
www.domain.com.au wont redirect to https://www.domain.com.au

The server is windows running IIS.
The wordpress installation I'm having trouble redirecting is a subfolder subdomain of the main website.

In the .htaccess I have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

IN the finctions.php file I have this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ssl_template_redirect', 1 );
function ssl_template_redirect() {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') === false ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
        exit();
    } 
}
```

I also have the Easy HTTPS (SSL) Redirection Wordpress plugin installed.

Does anyone know what might be the issue.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm looks like I fixed the problem.

I'm using w3 total cache for wordpress.
It has a setting under page cache for the following:
[image]

I disabled this option and it now is working.